# android class missing in Android project

Tags: java, android, sqlite, class

I'm trying to get a sqlite database to work, I'm following [this Youtube guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vW4LZ1TRsRM). I'm having trouble implementing my database helper class. As you can see from the photo, I have a DB_Controller class but I cannot use it as my NewCustomer class won't resolve the symbol. I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the project but I cannot resolve my problem.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGZDD.png)

Comment: You can also try tested and recommended solutions like Realm to handle database needs

Answer (score 0):

there is no such a class in Android SDK. Please watch the video more carefully, and see on [1:55](https://youtu.be/vW4LZ1TRsRM?t=1m55s) time the author starts to implement `DB_Controller` class manually.

Comment: I've created the DB_Controller class manually as the video shows, it's in the program structure tree on the left hand side of the picture. I cannot implement it and don't understand why I get the error message.

Comment: @MarkC, try rebuilding, or show the contents of your DB_Controller class, if rebuild not helping

Answer (score 0):

An update of Android Studio and plug-ins seems to have solved my problem. Spent 3 hours on this :(

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihOsl.png)

Move the db_controller.java to the same directory as your Main Activity.